# Entity Framework 4 - Delay Loading Expensive Fields

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

I know this same question was asked for Entity Framework 1, but now that Entity Framework 4 has come out, and Microsoft claims that it provides all of the features of Linq to Sql + more, does Entity Framework now support lazy loading expensive properties?  In Linq to Sql, this is extremely easy.  There's a Delay Loaded option on any property (accessible through the Designer) that can simply be toggled on or off.  Is there something similar in Entity Framework?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very important question! Did you find an answer somewhere else in the meantime?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I'm hoping this feature is hidden somewhere, but I haven't been able to find any reference to it.  I'm hoping this doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm just suffering from the same problem, urgently looking for a solution. I've asked at MS forum, see my answer below. (The answer is something like a "Yo" or "Nes".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab2a89f-f980-4f95-b8f7-7230566433bb/delayed-loading-of-binary-fields?forum=adodotnetentityframework) on the MS EF forum. As you see they provided a link to a description of [Table splitting in Entity Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622055915/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/10/13/table-splitting-in-entity-framework.aspx).

Basically the idea is to split one database table into more than one Entity which are associated by 1:1 relationships and then benefit from the usual lazy loading feature between related entities.

Not as comfortable as the delayed-loading-flag in LINQ to SQL in my opinion but at least a solution which does not require to touch your database table.

**Edit**: Finally MS support answered in the thread I've linked above that a "Delayed loading flag" like in LINQ to SQL definitely doesn't exist in Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the table splitting method. Works like a charm. Just create a second table with only a keyfield and a blob field, ono-to-one relation with the original image table. Delete de blob field from the image table.

Update the model and create the association between the image class and the blob class.

When you actualy need the blob field dont forget to "include" the blob table like this:

```
from a in dc.GeneralFile.include("Image").select(a => a.FileId, a.Image.Blob)
```

Hope it works out for you.

P.S. Tried to add a picture, but am not allowed